# finding partial derivative of a hard iron magnetometer calibration function

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, jacobian

I am currently working on an algorithm application and I am trying to reach the solution that I found in the reference, but I did not reach it
the function is
$$f(H_{i},(R,\beta)) = R - || H_{x}^2 + H_{y}^2 + H_{z}^2 + 2H_{x}\beta_{x} + 2H_{y}\beta_{y} + 2H_{z}\beta_{z} + \beta_{x}^2 + \beta_{y}^2 + \beta_{z}^2 ||^{1/2}$$

i get partial derivarive
$$\frac{\partial f(H_{i},(R,\beta))}{\partial \beta_{x}}  = \frac{-\left ( H_{x} + \beta_{x} \right )}{|| H_{x}^2 + H_{y}^2 + H_{z}^2 + 2H_{x}\beta_{x} + 2H_{y}\beta_{y} + 2H_{z}\beta_{z} + \beta_{x}^2 + \beta_{y}^2 + \beta_{z}^2 ||}$$

but i found a different sign at the reference solution
$$\frac{\partial f(H_{i},(R,\beta))}{\partial \beta_{x}}  = \frac{-\left ( H_{x} - \beta_{x} \right )}{|| H_{x}^2 + H_{y}^2 + H_{z}^2 + 2H_{x}\beta_{x} + 2H_{y}\beta_{y} + 2H_{z}\beta_{z} + \beta_{x}^2 + \beta_{y}^2 + \beta_{z}^2 ||}$$
is the reference solution is right why it got minus sign ?
, why can any body help?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: How did you get a negative sign? And what do the $\|$ mean? This is not a vector inside.